# How to install a rx callback with python-can?

Tags: python-3.x, can-bus

I'd like to have a function to receive incoming CANbus frames asynchronously.
I wrote the following, but the following issue:

```
    can.rxcallback(0, callback)
AttributeError: module 'can' has no attribute 'rxcallback'
```

My code is as follow:

```py
def reception():
    global count
    data = [0, 0, 0, memoryview(bytearray(8))]

    def callback(bus, reason):
        global count
        count += 1
        bus.recv(0, list=data)
        if reason == 0:
            pass
        elif reason == 1:
            pass  # fifo full
        elif reason == 2:
            # fifo overflow
            raise Exception("fifo overflow")

    can.rxcallback(0, callback)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken straight form python-can's documentation:

```
def print_message(msg: can.Message) -> None:
    """Regular callback function. Can also be a coroutine."""
    print(msg)


notifier = can.Notifier(bus, [print_message])
...
notifier.stop()
```

You create an instance of `Notifier` and register a list of listeners.

A listener is either a function taking a parameter of type `can.Message` or an instance of `Listener`.

After you have received all messages, call `stop()` on the notifier.

---

There is no method like `rxcallback` or similar on python-can.